# оплата онлайн PayPal

Tags: paypal, юридические-аспекты

Кто работал с подключением API PayPal к своему сайту и может рассказать как правила установки АПИ. Я старался найти ответы на форумах, но безуспешно. Я так понимаю, нужно регистрировать юридическое лицо ? Возможно, у кого-то есть статьи по тому, как правильно это сделать и сам этим занимался..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давно занимался этим.. Тогда частным лицам из России нельзя было принимать оплату, поэтому я, будучи в Таиланде, открывал там счёт и к нему привязывал якобы Тайский аккаунт PayPal, на который принимал оплату. Потом такой же трюк делал, когда был в Италии. Что-то наверняка поменялось за пару лет, и вроде бы, теперь можно принимать оплату не-юрлицам и в РФ.

Доступные сервисы PayPal [зависят от страны](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/howto_product_matrix/), в которой зарегистрирован аккаунт.

[Простой вариант](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/) приёма оплаты на сайте доступен во всех странах.

Напр. [для России](https://www.paypal.com/ru/webapps/mpp/merchant) доступны какие-то из решений по приёму платежей, но какие из них – только для юр. лиц, а какие есть и для частных лиц – я не знаю, надо разбираться.

Comment: спасибо. сейчас буду читать материал, который скинули.
сколько знакомых девов и никто не может помочь с этим вопросом.

Comment: [подробный пост на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/266091/) про интеграцию PayPal на сайт. Потребуется Business аккаунт.

Answer (score 0):

> Кто работал с подключением API PayPal к своему сайту и может рассказать как правила установки АПИ. Я старался найти ответы на форумах, но безуспешно. Я так понимаю, нужно регистрировать юридическое лицо ?

Да, все верно - требуется регистрация аккаунта юридического лица.

Вам по почте придет инструкция на их сервис с целью заполнения всех документов - сканов, банковских реквизитов.

Затем будет проверка банка на прием-получение платежей. На банковском счету -2-3 доллара должно быть.

На paypal сейчас есть техподдержка на русском языке - по телефону, тикетами.

Все это прошла.

После всех проверок вам позвонят и пришлют ссылку для интеграции платежей в свой магазин по API - это только приступаю.